# Is there a way to perform login authentication by clicking the URL link of the file uploaded to artifactory in the jfrog tool?

Tags: artifactory, jfrog-cli, jfrog-container-registry, jfrog-pipelines

I am using Jfrog's artifactory to store files for collaboration with others.

I shared the URL link of the file uploaded to artifactory so that other people could download it.

I expected other people to click the URL link, perform login authentication, and then download the file.

However, when other people click the link, a 404 status and the message 'Resource not found' are displayed.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AJHSO.png)

To perform login authentication, must enter the path excluding the file name in the url link.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WNyAp.png)

I want to perform login authentication just by clicking on the url link.

The curl command using basic auth or bearer token works well.

But this isn't what I want. Click on the URL Link to perform authentication and download the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are encountering this: https://jfrog.com/help/r/jfrog-platform-administration-documentation/hide-existence-of-unauthorized-resources

Please check if this box is checked. If it is please, uncheck it.

Comment: It was a great help. thank you